# Can I Polyurethane a room in sections

Tags: hardwood-floor, polyurethane, hardwood-refinishing

Hi I'm currently working on trying to finish the floor in my art room/studio in my home. It is an old hardwood floor, as the house was built in 1914 and I'm unsure of the age, finish or stain, all I know is it's rough and I would like to seal/polyurethane it. When we purchased the house the floors were carpet overtop the wood. The problem is I have several large things in this area that are difficult to move around. I'm curious if I can finish half of the room, move the stuff, and finish the other half. I'm not concerned with appearance, so differences in color or lines where sections meet is fine, I just need it smoother than it is now. Im not very knowledgeable about home improvement but if there are products like spray finish or clear sheet protectors, ways to smooth out my floor, or tips for finishing it please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not concerned with appearance, so differences in color or lines where sections meet is fine

Given that, yes, you can finish/refinish in sections. Where the sections meet will likely be initially obvious, but that will become somewhat less with time if all are prepared and finished similarly.

The main issue with refinishing a floor while there's still stuff in the room is two-fold. The floor will need to be sanded, and unless it's in the sort of shape where it barely needs refinished that **usually** involves a massive, heavy-duty rental sander. Which you can do the whole thing with in one day if you clear everything out. If you opt to leave stuff there, you'll have to cover everything left against extremely pervasive sanding dust, sand, finish and wait an adequate time for curing, then move everything to the finished side, cover it up against dust again, and repeat the process.

Getting some help moving things out and in may cost less than renting for two days, and the whole job will be done faster.

Comment: It may be a benefit to tape off and cover the not-to-be-finished-right-now part of the floor along a joint line.